# How do you make a css grid flow in a single row no wrap

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

```
...
.MusicRow {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 32px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 4.5vw 0;
}

.MusicRow .RowHeader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.MusicRow .RowHeader .Title {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: -0.04em;
    text-transform: none;
}

.MusicRow .Container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 24px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(220px,1fr));
    padding-right: 32px;
}
...
```

```
...
return (
<div className={style.MusicRow}>
   <div className={style.RowHeader}></div>
   <div className={style.Container}>
          {data.map(item => { return <RowItem key={item.id} info={item}/> }) }
    </div>
</div>
)
...
```

`grid-template-columns` is used to display a list of item components.

Right now I cannot get it to stop wrapping if the list exceeds a row or keep all items on a single row.
The goal is to show a slice of list of items on a single row and there will be a 'See all' link which will redirect to another page to show all items as a grid

Resizing for example could show 2-3 items at minimum, there is no maximum depending on how wide the window is, expanding should bring in more items from the right hand side into the row. There won't be overflow of partial items, all items will need to fit

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with react and the `render(` is just a distraction that blocks you from creating a snippet to show what's wrong. I would remove that

Comment: grid-auto-flow:column?

Comment: ^ and you set grid-auto-column:200px or any value

Comment: `max-height: var(--row-item-height);` and `overflow: hidden;` worked for me